# SQLite NOT LIKE statement in android

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I tried the following method to query for functiontitles not beginning with "Exhibitor Daily".

```
public Cursor fetchAllSchedulesByDate(String newConfDate){

  Cursor mCursor = db.query(SQLITE_TABLE, new String[] {
            KEY_ID, KEY_functiontitle, KEY_fucntioindate, KEY_functionStartTime, KEY_functionEndTime, KEY_functiondescription, KEY_LOCATIONNAME }, 
            KEY_fucntioindate + " = " + newConfDate + " AND " + KEY_functiontitle + " NOT LIKE 'Exhibitor Daily%'", null, null, null, null, null);

  if (mCursor != null) {
   mCursor.moveToFirst();
  }
  return mCursor;
 }
```

However, it seems to be ignoring the NOT LIKE clause in the query and the results set contains functiontitles beginning with "Exhibitor Daily" which is not what is expected. If I replace the NOT LIKE clause with `LIKE 'Exhibitor Daily%'`, it works correctly as expected and the results set contains only titles beginning with Exhibitor Daily. Can't see what could be wrong.

Comment: It looks like it would function.  Maybe it's the field delimiter.  I always use selection args so I don't have to worry so much about field delimiters.  String selection = RidesDatabaseHandler.KEY_PATH + "=?"; String[] selectionArgs = { (String) values.get(RidesDatabaseHandler.KEY_PATH) };

Comment: My bad! I forgot to also update my filter method with the NOT LIKE clause. Instead of scrolling through the list to see if the title was not displaying as expected, I was doing a filter search looking for the titles and because the filter was not updated, it was displaying the titles. It's only when I scrolled through the list did I realize that the clause in the query was working, I just needed to update the filter. duh!